# Twig: how to get views machine name, label, etc

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I include a view into a node via a viewreference field.
I apply dynamic classes to it like this:

```
{% set vuebloc_classes = [
'liste-vdl',
'label-' ~ node.field_inserer_liste.fieldDefinition.name | replace({"_" : "-"}),
'vue-' ~ rows[0]['content']['#row']._entity.getTitle(),
'vue-' ~ node.view.name,
'type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class
]%}
```

TWIG like this:

```
<aside {{ vuebloc_attribute.addClass(vuebloc_classes) }}>
    {{ content.field_inserer_liste.0 }}
  </aside>
```

I would to use the view machine name and/or display type as class, in addition to others. My trials aren't working for now.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried the 1st snippet code.